# AWS VPC Enable DNS Resolution: Unable to read internal endpoint from public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We have an VPC with 3 public subnets ans 3 private subnets.

Public subnets reach Internet across an Internet Gateway. Private subnets reach Internet across its own NAT Gateway (One for each).

We created some interface type Endpoints (secretManager, dkr-ecr...) Those Endpoints require *Enable DNS Resolution* feacture active in the VPC. We did it.

Now, our code running on private subnets works fine.

But instances in public subnet don't reach, for example, *https://<OUR_ACCOUNT>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com*

DNS resolution for *<OUR_ACCOUNT>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com* is now a private IP in our range.

And this IP is not listening for the service.

Any idea?

Comment: You want a private ip to be public? What was the purpose of adding the interface endpoints? by design they setup private access. do you want a split view and what will handle the traffic in this case?

Comment: @lloyd. I have created an VPC enpoint to avoid traffic from my private subnets across NAT gateway (have cost) for some services. This require Enable DNS Resolution feacture active in the VPC. So. The endpoint for this services are a private IP. My instances in private subnets reach the services. My instances in public subnets doesn't. The weird thing is that the private IP is from the public subnet range. <OUR_ACCOUNT>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com resolv 19.0.0.59. 19.0.0.0/16 its my VPC range. 19.0.[0-2].0/24 for public subnets. 19.0.[10-12].0/24 for private subnets. I have 3 of each.